# Searching for single words and combination words in Ruby

Tags: ruby, frequency, stop-words

I want my output to search and count the frequency of the words "candy" and "gram", but also the combinations of "candy gram" and "gram candy," in a given text (whole_file.)
I am currently using the following code to display the occurrences of "candy" and "gram," but when I aggregate the combinations within the %w, only the word and frequencies of "candy" and "gram" display. Should I try a different way? thanks so much.

```
myArray = whole_file.split

stop_words= %w{ candy gram 'candy gram' 'gram candy' } 

nonstop_words = myArray - stop_words

key_words = myArray - nonstop_words

frequency = Hash.new (0)

key_words.each { |word| frequency[word] +=1 }

key_words = frequency.sort_by {|x,y| x }

key_words.each { |word, frequency| puts word + ' ' + frequency.to_s }
```

Comment: I do not underderstand, "...display text that counts the number of times "candy" and "gram" show up". Do you mean you want to count the number of times each of the words "candy" and "gram" show up, and display that result?  I realize there is a second part to the question.

Comment: Hi Cary. Yes, I want my output to display the frequency of the words "candy"and "gram" in addition to displaying the frequency of combination of the words, "candy gram" in my text. I'll clarify the question, thanks for helping me clear that up.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're after [n-grams](http://www.sitepoint.com/natural-language-processing-ruby-n-grams/). You could break the text into combinations of consecutive words in the first place, and then count the occurrences in the resulting array of word groupings. Here's an example:

```
whole_file = "The big fat man loves a candy gram but each gram of candy isn't necessarily gram candy"

[["candy"], ["gram"], ["candy", "gram"], ["gram", "candy"]].each do |term|
  terms = whole_file.split(/\s+/).each_cons(term.length).to_a
  puts "#{term.join(" ")} #{terms.count(term)}"
end
```

**EDIT:** As was pointed out in the comments below, I wasn't paying close enough attention and was splitting the file on each loop which is obviously not a good idea, especially if it's large. I also hadn't accounted for the fact that the original question may've need to sort by the count, although that wasn't explicitly asked.

```
whole_file = "The big fat man loves a candy gram but each gram of candy isn't necessarily gram candy"
# This is simplistic. You would need to address punctuation and other characters before
# or at this step.
split_file = whole_file.split(/\s+/)
terms_to_count = [["candy"], ["gram"], ["candy", "gram"], ["gram", "candy"]]
counts = []

terms_to_count.each do |term|
  terms = split_file.each_cons(term.length).to_a
  counts << [term.join(" "), terms.count(term)]
end

# Seemed like you may need to do sorting too, so here that is:
sorted = counts.sort { |a, b| b[1] <=> a[1] }
sorted.each do |count|
  puts "#{count[0]} #{count[1]}"
end
```

Comment: I'll give this a try @dnunez24! also, I noticed you're from the city of Roses! that's my hometown!

Comment: Also, just gave this a try and I got an empty output. :/

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't write the complete program to output the string you needed. You'd need to take the result of the counts I was showing in the example and make it into the output you require. I'm not a Portland native, but been here for a handful of years now and love it. :)

Comment: @dnunez24 - you might want to `split` outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, @UriAgassi. I actually had done that previously but edited my post. Good catch. I will amend it again.

Answer (score 0):

**Strip punctuation and convert to lower-case**

The first thing you probably want to do is remove all punctuation from the string holding the contents of the file and then convert what's left to lower case, the latter so you don't have worry about counting 'Cat' and 'cat' as the same word. Those two operations can be done in either order.

Changing upper-case letters to lower-case is easy:

```
text = whole_file.downcase
```

To remove the punctuation it is probably easier to decide what to keep rather than what to discard. If we only want to keep lower-case letters, you can do this:

```
text = whole_file.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '')
```

That is, substitute an empty string for all characters other than (`^`) lowercase letters.<sup>1</sup>

**Determine frequency of individual words**

If you want to count the number of times `text` contains the word `'candy'`, you can use the method [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-scan) on the string `text` and then determine the size of the array that is returned:

```
text.scan(/\bcandy\b/).size
```

`scan` returns an array with every occurrence of the string `'candy'`; `.size` returns the size of that array. Here `\b` ensures `'candy gram'` has a word "boundary" at each end, which could be whitespace or the beginning or end of a line or the file. That's to prevent `candycane' from being counted.

A second way is to convert the string `text` to an array of words, as you have done<sup>2</sup>:

```
myArray = text.split
```

If you don't mind, I'd like to call this:

```
words = text.split
```

as I find that more expressive.<sup>3</sup>

The most direct way to determine the number of times `'candy'` appears is to use the method [Enumberable#count](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count), like this:

```
words.count('candy')
```

You can also use the array difference method, [Array#-](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-2D), as you noted:

```
words.size - (words - ['candy']).size
```

If you wish to know the number of times either 'candy' or 'gram' appears, you could of course do the above for each and sum the two counts. Some other ways are:

```
words.size - (myArray - ['candy', 'gram']).size
words.count { |word| word == 'candy' || word = 'gram' }
words.count { |word| ['candy', 'gram'].include?(word) }
```

**Determine the frequency of all words that appear in the text**

Your use of a hash with a default value of zero was a good choice:

```
def frequency_of_all_words(words)
  frequency = Hash.new(0)
  words.each { |word| frequency[word] +=1 }
  frequency
end
```

I wrote this as a method to emphasize that `words.each...` does not return `frequency`. Often you would see this written more compactly using the method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), which returns the hash ("object"):

```
def frequency_of_all_words(words)
  words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word, h| h[word] +=1 }
end
```

Once you have the hash `frequency` you can sort it as you did:

```
frequency.sort_by {|word, freq| freq }
```

or

```
frequency.sort_by(&:last)
```

which you could write:

```
frequency.sort_by {|_, freq| freq }
```

since you aren't using the first block variable.  If you wanted the most frequent words first:

```
frequency.sort_by(&:last).reverse
```

or

```
frequency.sort_by {|_, freq| -freq }
```

All of these will give you an array. If you want to convert it back to a hash (with the largest values first, say):

```
Hash[frequency.sort_by(&:last).reverse]
```

or in Ruby 2.0+,

```
frequency.sort_by(&:last).reverse.to_h
```

**Count the number of times a substring appears**

Now let's count the number of times the string `'candy gram'` appears. You might think we could use `String#scan` on the string holding the entire file, as we did earlier<sup>4</sup>:

```
text.scan(/\bcandy gram\b/).size
```

The first problem is that this won't catch 'candy\ngram'; i.e., when the words are separated by a newline character. We could fix that by changing the regex to     `/\bcandy\sgram\b/`. A second problem is that 'candy gram' might have been 'candy. Gram' in the file, in which case you might not want to count it.

A better way is to use the method [Enumerable#each_cons](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) on the array `words`. The easiest way to show you how that works is by example:

```
words = %w{ check for candy gram here candy gram again }
  #=> ["check", "for", "candy", "gram", "here", "candy", "gram", "again"]
enum = words.each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["check", "for", "candy", "gram", "here", "candy",
  #                  "gram", "again"]:each_cons(2)>
enum.to_a
  #=> [["check", "for"], ["for",  "candy"], ["candy", "gram"],
  #    ["gram", "here"], ["here", "candy"], ["candy", "gram"],
  #    ["gram", "again"]]
```

`each_cons(2)` returns an enumerator; I've converted it to an array to display its contents.

So we can write

```
words.each_cons(2).map { |word_pair| word_pair.join(' ') }
  #=> ["check for", "for candy", "candy gram", "gram here",
  #    "here candy", "candy gram", "gram again"]
```

and lastly:

```
words.each_cons(2).map { |word_pair|
  word_pair.join(' ') }.count { |s| s == 'candy gram' }
  #=> 2
```

<sup>1 If you also wanted to keep dashes, for hyphenated words, change the regex to `/[^-a-z]/` or `/[^a-z-]/`.</sup>

<sup>2 Note from [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-split) that `.split` is the same as both `.split(' ')` and `.split(/\s+/)`).</sup>

<sup>3 Also, Ruby's naming convention is to use lower-case letters and underscores ("snake-case") for variables and methods, such as `my_array`.</sup>